# Why do my localstorage variables both return true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like a website and whenever a user clicks on the purchase under a certain product they shall be taken to their cart and then they shall see their product's image there and I want the image to change from shirt to sneakers but it doesn't. So I came up with the idea of using localstorage and I did the following in my addToCart script file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var isShoes = false
    var isShirt = false

    $('#purchaseShoes').on('click', function()
    {
        alert('Sneakers')
        var Shoes = localStorage.setItem('img_shoes', '/static/Images/Sneakers.png')
        isShoes = localStorage.setItem('isShoes', true)
    })
    $('#purchaseShirt').on('click', function()
    {
        alert('T-shirt')
        var Shirt = localStorage.setItem('img_shirt', '/static/Images/Images/T-Shirt.png')
        isShirt = localStorage.setItem('isShoes', true)

    })
})
```

But apparently the script registers both buttons as clicked and whenever I go to my cartControl script and I test it out it gives me back my both values as true. Why does it show me both, when I've clicked one of the buttons only? I've checked the html and their id's are different. Shall I be using an if in the addToScript script???
Here is the cartControl script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var Shoes = localStorage.getItem('img_shoes')
    var Shirt = localStorage.getItem('img_shirt')

    var isShirt = localStorage.getItem('isShirt')
    var isShoes = localStorage.getItem('isShoes')

    var quantityNumber = 1;
    var shirtPrice = 25.00;
    var shirt = document.getElementById('shirtTotal')
    var Quantity = document.getElementById('Quantity')

    alert(isShoes)
    alert(isShirt)
    $('#btnQuantity').on('click', function()
    {
        
        
        quantityNumber+=1;
        Quantity.innerText = quantityNumber;
        shirt.innerText = "Total Price: " + "$" + (quantityNumber*shirtPrice);
        
        
    })
    
    
    
    
})
```

Comment: localStorage lives as long as you clear it, so if you `setItem` to `true` it will always be `true` unless you `setItem` to `false` or clear it.

Comment: So that's in action even when I set the localstorage only when a button is clicked? I mean I've got 2 buttons and on each button clicked i set the localstorage variable. Shouldn't the variable in the button, that wasn't clicked, be not created?

Comment: you have `localStorage.setItem('isShoes', true)` in both buttons clicks

Comment: it won't be created. But if you clicked on the second button some time before, you'll still have it set to `true`.

Comment: Thank you all people, the problem was solved, thanks to all of you! Thank you !!